# Why when calculating SID2 value SID1 should be multiplied by 40 when using ASN.1 standard?

Tags: snmp, asn.1, mib

As standard says (http://rsdn.ru/article/ASN/ASN.xml) while encoding OBJECT IDENTIFIER it's mandatory to set SID1 either 0,1 or 2 and SID2 should have corresponding values in order to have only approach to decode SID1 and SID2.

So, why the formula to evaluate encoded SID2 is SID1*40 + SID2 ? What is for 40 there?

Comment: Why would you link us to the Russian-language version of the standard? Not many people here will have use for it...

Comment: @Jolta, you are right, sorry, it's my fault. I'll be more forward-looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This came from OID namespace restrictions (IIRC, X.208). There are only three top-level roots (itu-t, iso and joint-itu-t) and second level is limited to 40 arcs (0-39) when root namespace is either itu-t or iso. Thus, it is possible to unambigously encode first two arcs with a single byte.

Answer (score 2):

This is a legacy from the early days of ASN.1.  Arcs 0 and 1 in the OID tree are limited to 40 children each (0-39), while Arc 2 has no limit on the number of children.  In order to conserve bits on the wire, the first two OID nodes are represented in a single byte (even for Arc 2 if its child is less than 47).  The selection of "40" was just an arbitrary number chosen for convenience to allow easy calculations for fitting the first two OID arcs into a single byte.